# DBGhost with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs-migration, dbghost

We are currently using DBGhost with our SQL server database. The current version control tool is VSS along with which we are using  DBGhost. Now, we want to migrate to TFS and have some questions about using DBGhost with TFS.

1. Can DBGhost work with TFS?
2. If yes, what kind of output it expects from TFS?

   a. Just the checked in database file (table, stored procedure .sql files etc.) same as VSS

   b. OR It needs TFS to run a build after the files are checked in and then DBGhost looks at the results of the Build?

What I meant to ask is, for using DB Ghost with TFS, is it okay to put all the code from VSS into TFS just like that OR it should be first converted to a Visual Studio Database Solution using SSDT and then put into TFS and then define Builds in TFS that would run after every checkin?

Answer (score 1):

DB Ghost works fine with TFS and we have many customers using it.  In essence all you have to do is a command line pull from the TFS respository to a local folder and then point DB Ghost at that set of folders, the rest is just the same.

Comment: Thanks Malcolm. When I use the DB ghost wizard, how do I connect from DB Ghost to TFS? For VSS, we just select the vssscc file, but how do I do it for TFS?
Can you please elaborate on the process?

Comment: We are now using TFS command line to get the latest from VSS into a physical folder. Then DBGhost uses this physical folder instead of VSS.